# How do I read a file without extension?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

1. I have just download some file from server "hdfs dfs -get  /user/hive/warehouse/"
2. from the downloaded folder the file has no extension (I was expecting it is a parquet file) and when I use command "file *" to check it shows 000000_0 : data
3. I use val rddFromFile = spark.sparkContext.textFile("path") and it shows that each line is not delimited or with "?" in between each field

May I know what file is it and how should I read it into a proper database/dataframe? I try split("?") but it just doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Use `parquet-tools` utility to view the data.

`hadoop jar ./parquet-tools-<VERSION>.jar cat <hdfs-location-file>`

Check this link for more about parquet tools. https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools

OR

simply do `hdfs dfs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/000000_0`

If it is parquet then structure is as below.

**Parquet file:**

At a high level, the parquet file consists of a header, one or more blocks and footer. The parquet file format contains a 4-byte magic number in the header `(PAR1)` and at the end of the footer. This is a magic number indicating that the file is in parquet format.

Use `orcfiledump` utility to view the content
The ORC file dump utility comes with hive (0.11 or higher):

`hive --orcfiledump <hdfs-location-of-orc-file>`

**ORC file:**

ORC is a columnar file format. You can visualize the structure of an ORC file as an area that is divided into Header, body and footer.

**Header Section:**
The Header contains the text `ORC` in case some tools are required to determine the type of file while processing.

Also, you can get files on windows, then you can just open files in the editor(notepad++). Although, it is a binary file. Still You can see in the first line like `ORC` or `PAR1` followed by some other encrypted characters.

Comment: Hi Vijay, thanks for the answer I have just checked by using hdfs dfs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/000000_0 and it seem like a text file than parquet file, weird that if I import it as text file the delimiter is "?" and I couldn't split it by .split("?")